# Cordova 3.4.0 and Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: cordova, xcode5.1

I'm building my first app with cordova/phonegap. Everything was just fine until I updated my iPhone 5S to iOS 7.1 AND Xcode to 5.1.1

Now I keep on getting this error:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
BUILD FAILED
```

In xcode I see my provisioning profile, and it's still valid.

I see some people is having architecture problems. I'm not, but at the moment I can't run my app on any device, but just on the simulator. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

We [just released `cordova-ios` v3.4.1](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/04/09/tools-ios-release.html) to fix a bunch of issues with xcode 5.1.  3.4.0 is known to not work.  I advise upgrade and report back if the issue persists.

Comment: I'm working with Phonegap, I updated cordova with "npm update" and if I run "cordova -v" I actually see that it's been updated to v3.4.1-0.1.0. BUT when i build my app, using "phonegap build ios" or "cordova build ios", in ios/CordovaLib folder I still see version 3.4.0. I guess I messed up something and I have no clue how to fix it, maybe I need to create a new phonegap project and restart from scratch (...?)
I also tried to uninstall Xcode 5.1 and reinstall 5.0, but nothing changed.
I can succesfully **build** the app, but I keep on getting the same error about the provisioning profile...

Comment: I guess I solved this, restarting from scratch:
1) uninstall phonegap AND cordova via npm, then install cordova (not phonegap)
2) create a new cordova app 
3) add ios platform then launch **cordova run ios**  
IT WORKS!! **BUT** if I install any plugin via plugman it stops working and the "provisioning profile" error comes back. 
By now, if I install plugins using _cordova plugin add_ command, it seems it's working.

Comment: So `phonegap` is a wrapper around `cordova` that doesn't get updated quite as often.  Its possible they aren't on 3.4.1 yet.  If you want a cordova-ios 3.4.1 based project, you have to use a CLI which is at least that version.  You shouldn't need to uninstall `phonegap` but you will need to remove and re-add the ios platform using either CLI that supports 3.4.1.  If you are using a CLI, you should not be using `plugman` to add plugins, but rather `cordova plugin add` or `phonegap plugin add`.  If that does not work, then please report back, or better yet, file a bug on our JIRA issue tracker.

Comment: I knew this couldn't be over... I can add some plugins, and some not, with 'cordova plugin add'. With File and Media it works fine, with Barcode (com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner) it doesn't... The error is "file [..] com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm not found". Is there a way to manually add a plugin, without using 'cordova plugin add'/'plugman'?

Comment: @Francesca I just tried, and it fails for me as well.  I think that plugin is just broken, and I would file a bug with them.  As far as adding plugins manually: you can, but it isn't pretty, and you are likely to shoot yourself in the foot.  If this is something you really want to consider, I would drop using cordova-cli entirely and just use the old "project-oriented" workflow.  I don't actually think that what you want, though.  You just want a not broken barcode scanner plugin :)  Good luck!